# OCR of Chinese characters with File Insert

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to OCR a File Insert in to Google Drive. The image being inserted contains Chinese characters. The images is converted to a Google Doc as usual when OCRing but none of the text is extracted.

According to the docs you should use "ocrLanguage" with a value of an ISO 639-1 code. But there is no mention of which languages are supported.

I tried using "zh" which the API rejects as an invalid value.

I tried using "zh-Hans" which I found in the old Google-Docs API documentation. This does 
not return an error but no OCR occurs.

I tried using a "" but also no OCR.

According to the docs this parameter is just a hint and will be overriden if the OCR engine can work out the language.

So my questions are:

1. Has anyone successfully OCR a image containing Chinese characters?
2. Does anyone have a list of supported languages?

NOTES: When uploading the image in a browser the OCR language drop-down contains Chinese (simplified and traditional) and this method successfully extracts the text.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have a script for Chinese OCR, written about 2 year ago. It worked perfectly, code like this (using PHP library):

   $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
       'data' => $data,
       'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
       'ocr' => true,
       'ocrLanguage' => 'zh-Hans',
       'convert' => true,
   ));

Now it not working for "zh-Hans", but working for "en" language normally.
It takes about 10-15 seconds for waiting response from Google API, so Google trying to complete OCR, but it seems have a problems on side of Google API.

1. Supported languages for chinese is zh-Hans, zh-Hant as whitten here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/ (but that is old documentation).
   Languages in web interface OCR html select are the same:

   Chinese (Simplified)
   Chinese (Traditional)

Can you add "google-drive-sdk" tag to this question, as recommended here https://developers.google.com/drive/support

Comment: Thanks for the info on the tags.  

I have re-run some test with some new images  
ocrLanguage=en Works fine  
ocrLanguage=fr Works fine  
ocrLanguage=zh-Hans Creates a Google doc and embeds the image but not text extraction occurs  
ocrLanguage=zh-Hant Causes the API to return the following error  

`{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "ocrLanguage"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}`

Comment: Yes, zh-Hant causes the API error, zh-Hant is not supported by API (my API library is about 2 yeas ago installed, and now Google have no normal PHP library, only beta version without actual documentation an so on). So i think, Google have no resources now to develop Drive API libraries, maybe them solve these problems later...